# How to reference non-rust (config) files in my crate?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a number of config files listed in a config/ directory in my package, and I include them in my Cargo.toml:

`include = ["src/**/*", "README.md", "config/**/*"]`

When I import my crate, I can see that the config files are being included. But in my code I reference to them as `config/file.config`. This works within my project, but breaks when the crate is imported in a different project.

I assume the filepath has to include something else, but I can't find what. Any tips?

A lot of threads I could easily find all related to importing `.rs` files, or bundling files in an executable using `include_str` macros, but I have a crate here, not an executable. And I have ~83 config files (one for a country, 83 countries), so I'd rather not include them piece by piece like this.

When I reference the file in my tests, it works as expected and I can read the data from the file. When using my crate in another project, it fails as it cannot find the file.

So far I've tried several variations of the path, including the `CARGO_MANIFEST_DIR` env var as a prefix, but no dice. I also think doing something like `target/build/...package/config` is also not a good idea for many, many reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best idea is to include them in the binary. You don't have to include them one-by-one; the [`include_dir`](https://docs.rs/include_dir/) crate has got you covered.

If you insist on not doing that, I believe your best bet is to copy the files to the target directory using a build script. [The build script's current directory will be the package's directory](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#inputs-to-the-build-script), and [it has access to the target directory via the `OUT_DIR` environment variable](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html#environment-variables-cargo-sets-for-build-scripts). You can just copy the files, but remember to set Cargo to track changes via [`cargo:rerun-if-changed`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#rerun-if-changed) (you can watch the entire directory at once).

Comment: | in the binary
But it's a crate, which is just uploaded as source code right?

Including it isn't a problem, that's what the `include` keyword in my Cargo.toml already does, as per the docs:
"The exclude and include fields can be used to explicitly specify which files are included when packaging a project to be published, and certain kinds of change tracking (described below)."

So my files _are_ there, and as mentioned when I run `cargo package` they are there as expected. But the file path has changed and I don't see how I can get that path correctly?

Comment: @CodeGhost You need to include it so that the build script can access it, but it's still not in a path you should access (the user's package cache).